# xcode Images in lines in both rotated and normal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a view with 20 objects that are 150x150 in size. They're in rows and each row has 4 objects and in total there are 5 rows.

This works fine as is in the horizontal view, but when I switch to vertizal view things go weird. Most of the items are hidden off the screen.

If I apply the constrains to each like so.
[image]

The end result looks like this when rotated:
[image]

Can the constrains be used to accomplish what I want? (Get the images be in line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UICollectionView for it and apply constraints on collectionView it will handle out  everything and will manage your contents.

Comment: Thank you. I actually thought about using collectionview, but didn't really figure how it would solve my problem. Now that you said I can apply constraints to it, that'll solve my issue.